# How to save the painted control as a bitmap?

Tags: c#, bitmap, paint

I have a picturebox (pictureBox1), and it gets lines drawn on it, from the paint event. I was wondering how to convert that drawing (with the lines) to a bitmap, and save it as a file. I've tried:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox.Height);
pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pictureBox1.Bounds);
bmp.Save("MyImage.bmp");
```

But that is a blank image, without the lines. Does anyone know how I can save it with the lines? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use CreateGraphics(), use the Paint event instead.

Comment: I didn't, and the pictureBox1 is drawn on from the paint event. @ Hans Passant

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the [PictureBox.Bounds property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but instead use a simple [Rectangle object/structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wcdy991.aspx) filled with the `PictureBox' width and height like this:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
bitmap.Save("c:\\temp\\image.bmp");
```

Using the `Bounds` property you are fetching the correct size of the picture box control, but depending on the position not the `0,0` coordinate, but the control position, which leads to an empty bitmap.

Comment: I do not know if this will work in my case because i used the paint event to draw lines on the control pictureBox1.

Comment: I have updated my answer, the code works when you use the paint event graphics oject to draw into the picturebox control (and not using the image).

Answer (score 0):

```
            int bitmapX = 100
            int bitmapY = 100

            Bitmap imgToSave = new Bitmap(bitmapX, bitmapY);
            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(imgToSave);

            // draw on the image with
            gfx.DrawLine() // or whatever you want to draw

            // save the screenshot
            string saveFilePath = Application.StartupPath + "\<name of the image>.png";
            imgToSave.Save(saveFilePath, ImageFormat.Png);
```

This is a code snippet that works for me.